# Save Macro results to Excel sheet - VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel sheet (.xlsm) running SQL code. I have added a run button to the Macro sheet to run the query and then output the results in a network folder. The problem is the only form I can seem to get it to work is in Text. I would like it to export to an Excel (.xlsx) file. My module contents is as follows:

```
 Sub Run()

    Sheets("QM_INQ_DATA").Range("A1").ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False

    ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
        "Z:\QMDaily\Queue Manager INQ Daily Report " & Format(Date - 1, "MM.DD.YYYY") & ".xlsx" _
        , FileFormat:=51, CreateBackup:=False

End Sub
```

I really know nothing about VBA so Im sure this is an easy fix.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have trouble saving as an `.xlsx` file, since that it reserved for macro-free workbooks, and obviously, your workbook has a macro. Instead, you can create a new workbook in VBA, store the results of the query in the new workbook, then save it as `.xlsx`. 
I understand you have little experience in VBA, but I wouldn't expect anyone from SO to write the complete macro for you...

Comment: Oh I def don't expect anyone to wrote it for me, I was just hoping it would be an easy fix. Thank you!